# How to write a program in gwbasic for adding the natural numbers for 1 to 100?

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, gw-basic

I am trying to write a program for adding the natural numbers from 1 to n (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n). However, the sum appears 1 when I use `if` statement. And when I use `for-next` statement there is a syntax error that I don't understand.

`if`:

```
30 let s = 0
40 let i = 1
50 s = s + i
60 i = i + 1
70 if i<=n, then goto 50
80 print s
```

`for-next`:

```
30 let i, s
40 s = 0
50 for i = 1 to n
60 s = s + i
70 next i
80 print n
```

1. When I take n = 10, the `if` statement code gives a result of 1, but it should be 55.
2. When I try to use the `for-next` statement, it gives no result saying that there is a syntax error in 30.

Why is this happening?

Comment: ((1 + n) * n)/2 ... is the formula to compute directly your sum!!! .... :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code works in this [online Basic interpreter](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_basic_online.php).

```
10 let n = 100
30 let s = 0
40 let i = 1
50 s = s + i
60 i = i + 1
70 if i <= n then goto 50 endif
80 print s
```

I initialised `n` on the line labelled 10, removed the comma on the line labelled 70 and added an `endif` on the same line.

This is the `for-next` version:

```
30 let n = 100
40 let s = 0
50 for i = 1 to n
60 s = s + i
70 next i
80 print s
```

(btw, the sum of the first `n` natural numbers is `n(n+1)/2`:

```
10 let n = 100
20 let s = n * (n + 1) / 2
30 print s
```

)

Comment: The `endif` is nonsense. This is needed in _Ya Basic_, but the question is about _GW-BASIC_.  There it's just junk that gets ignored by the interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is this happening? Where am I mistaking?
>
> ```
> 30 let s = 0
> 40 let i = 1
> 50 s = s + i
> 60 i = i + 1
> 70 if i<=n, then goto 50
> 80 print s
> ```

Fix #1: Initialize variable 'n':

```
20 let n = 10
```

Fix #2: Remove comma from line 70:

```
70 if i<=n then goto 50
```

> ```
> 30 let i, s
> 40 s = 0
> 50 for i = 1 to n
> 60 s = s + i
> 70 next i
> 80 print n
> ```

Fix #1: Initialize variable 'n':

```
30 let n = 10
```

Fix #2: Print 's' instead of 'n':

```
80 print s
```